# Why friction causes energy to be lost in terms of heat when it appears to be an energy transfer mechanicsm?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, friction, dissipation

For example, when we move/walk, we apply a force (via friction) on earth, and the earth in turn on us. So essentially I see it as an energy transfer as follows:

Suppose I move in same direction as earths rotation. Here I am applying a force in such a way as to increase my velocity from initial 
$\Omega_{earth} \times radius_{earth}$ 
, so as to move relative to earth. I also reduce earth's angular rotation during this walking motion due to force I applied on earth. As a whole the system has the same energy.

In light of this, friction doesn't appear as a heat dissipative force to me.

Comment: As long as your feet aren't dragging or sliding, the friction force does no work and no heat is generated. Ask yourself: do tire threads heat up when driving your car?

Comment: *In light of this, friction doesn't appear as a heat dissipative force to me.* Oh but it is: just rub your hands together vigorously for a minute or so!

Comment: Friction doesn't just produce heat.  Most sliding objects also produce sound, which is acoustic energy leaving the scene.  Friction can also cause particles to move.

Comment: Static friction does not cause energy dissipation to heat.  Only kinetic friction causes such energy dissipation due to the relative movement of the adjacent surfaces.

Comment: @Gert I understand exactly what you are getting at when writing *do tire threads heat up when driving a car” but unfortunately? Tires do heat up due to another mechanism - hysteresis.

Comment: @Farcher: of course but that has nothing to do with friction *as we are discussing here* (but it does have to do with another type of friction).

Comment: Interesting views on the problem. From what I can tell so far, it seems that friction could or could not be dissipative (in terms of heat) depending on the situation.               In the case of walking or vehicle stopping (without sliding), there should be no heat generated at Point of Contact with ground at least (The brakes may heat up) and only energy transfer takes place with the Earth. It kind of makes sense as @ChesterMiller pointed out, that kinetic friction would cause heating.

Comment: @Gert Actually, I think tire treads may heat up when driving your car. I would think the treads alternatively "squeeze" and relax as the treads make and break contact with the road. Consequently, there is relative motion of the molecules of the tire tread material. However, this heating is probably quite small compared to the increase in tire air temperature due to compression of the air.

Comment: @BobD: totally agreed: hysteresis causes slight heating. But that has nothing to do with the friction force on the road surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing static friction. Static friction is not dissipative. It's only when your foot skids on the surface that the friction force becomes sliding or kinetic friction. It is only sliding or kinetic friction that dissipates energy in the form of heat.

Hope this helps.